# Why ssl tag is called ssl instead of tls?

Tags: discussion

SSL was renamed into TLS long ago. Some people still continue using term SSL when referring to it though actually it's TLS.

Do you think that it's a good idea to rename tag ssl into tls?

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia TLS page:

> TLS is an IETF standards track protocol, last updated in RFC 5246, and
>   is based on the earlier SSL specifications developed by Netscape
>   Communications

TLS 1.2 is the current version, which is based on SSL 3.0

For all practical purposes, TLS 1.2 and SSL 3 are treated as interchangeable, but as earlier versions are still in use, I don't think a tag synonym is appropriate.

Comment: Do you think it might be necessary or practical to have per-version tags for SSL?

Comment: @Iszi Currently too few questions ask about specifics of versions of TLS or SSL. Thus version tags aren't needed

Comment: The [tag:ssl] and [tag:tls] tags [are already synonyms](http://security.stackexchange.com/tags/ssl/synonyms). What surprises me is that [tag:https] is also included in this group. Perhaps also of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131414/148833